# How can I use javax.tools.JavaCompiler; to compile all dependencies?

Tags: java, compilation

If I run a java application using a tool like netbeans, it will compile all the required .java files.

I have a folder with maybe 5 java files, one names Main.java. 
I want to be able to compile Main.java, and the other files in the same directory so that I am able to then run main.java.

I currently have this:

```
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    compiler.run(null, null, null, srcDirectory.getPath()+"/Main.java");
```

But this says that there are classes missing (of course) as it did not compile the others.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that programmatically? Just use javac ... or Ant if you are already using netbeans ...

Comment: I think you need to supply a custom [`StandardJavaFileManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html), but have never tried it.